# Remember command line variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess

I want to make the command line run in python.

For Example:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('set /A x = 5', shell=True)  
subprocess.call('echo %x%', shell=True)
```

I'd like that i remember the value 5 that x was set to. But instead it echos just `%x%` as a string.

Comment: I think you really need to refresh your knowledge on *what* environment variables are, and how they're implemented on the system level. What you want to do simply doesn't work that way.

Comment: Reconsider setting up the variables in your script instead, and pass them as arguments/variables in each subprocess call.

Comment: I'm trying to make a interactive command line in python

Comment: @Jake Then use `subprocess.Popen` instead and keep the session alive, and use `process.stdin.write`/`process.stdout.read` instead. Using `process.poll()` will monitor if the process has died.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `subprocess` means very concretely that you run another process. The process in which the variable was set will no longer exist when control returns from the subprocess back to Python.

Try

```
import os
import subprocess

env = os.environ.copy()
env['x'] = '5'
subprocess.check_call(
    'echo %x%',
    shell=True,
    env=env)
```

Notice also the switch to `check_call` - it probably doesn't matter a great deal here, but you should usually check for subprocess failures.

Comment: (I fortunately don't have access to Windows so I can't test this. I recall the number and placement of percent signs for environment expansion varies between scenarios in subtle and bewildering ways.)

Comment: Nah, placement and number of percent signs are always before+after in (environment) variable expansion. Maybe you're thinking of for-loop variables..?

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks, it's been a good number of years since I needed to maintain an active knowledge of batch file syntax so I'm not sure, but I guess you are probably right.

Comment: Preferably i want to keep a Popen() open, read the output, then give it more input, so it would remember the variables

Comment: That's not at all what you are asking, though. This can readily be adapted to `Popen`; it accepts the same `env=` keyword argument. Maybe accept this and ask a new question with your *actual* requirements if you need more help.